# Calling CustomVision prediction API from Python - second time is not the charm

Tags: python, microsoft-custom-vision

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.prediction import CustomVisionPredictionClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

endpoint = 'https://####customvision-prediction.cognitiveservices.azure.com'
project_id = '####8db4-66e8-40b3-aa4a-fe3cbb30da35'
prediction_key = '####1670040b44499a8178ffe59be76e'
project_name = '####Test'

credential = CognitiveServicesCredentials(prediction_key)
predict = CustomVisionPredictionClient(endpoint, credential)

with open("./TallowTest1.jpg", mode="rb") as image_data:
    tallowresult = predict.detect_image(project_id, project_name, image_data)
```

I've now created the CustomVision resources twice in Azure, I think I have it right now.  I selected both a training and a prediction service.  Then went to customvision.ai and created a project.  I uploaded photos and trained the model.  Now, I'm trying the most simplistic Python script possible and still getting errors.  The most recent one is this:

```
...
    raise models.CustomVisionErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.prediction.models._models_py3.CustomVisionErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'PermissionDenied'
```

Note, that I'm **perfectly** willing to share keys at this point.  This is only a test and I can't get it working.  I'll share every key if someone will show me how to get this working.  I feel like I've tried every combination of keys, endpoints, project ids.  And I get different error messages in different cases but nothing is working.

Comment: I am not sure about azure so I will try to address in aws context. Did you check if this project has the necessary iamroles and arns?

Comment: thanks for the comment, I'm pretty sure the keys are the access point.  It's why we're told not to share them.

Comment: I face similar issues in aws, like region discrepancy, roles, ......last thing would be recreating all the services